# Contact Summary Editor Extension Question

Tags: extension, contact-summary-editor

I am using CiviCRM 5.19.4 and Drupal 8. I need to customize the Contact Summary page - installed the extension Contact Summary Editor successfully. All is good, added all the contact information that I want displayed. However, I need to add events and contributions for the contact to the summary page, but this information isn't displaying on the fields that are available to select from when creating a new block.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of the [Extended Reports](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports) for Events and Contributions respectively to display on the contact summary screen. Go to the Display Options tab and select '*Make available for contact summary page (requires contact layout editor extension)*'.

[image]